# Convert $1.75\times10^{15}$ to IEEE-32 format?

Tags: floating-point

$1.75\times10^{15}$

I know how to convert decimal to binary

$(1.75)_{10}$ is equal to $(1.11)_2$

But to represent $10^{15}$ is the main problem for me. I can solve the question but this is the point where I got stuck.
How can I represent $10^{15}$ in base 2 ?

Comment: What about converting 1750000000000000 to binary? Because that's the exact same number.

Comment: There's a big difference between writing $1.75\times 10^{15}$ in binary, and writing it in IEEE-32 (single precision floating point) form. I answer below to the latter. The former is done by remembering that 1 in the $i$-th place has a value of $2^{i}$ (where the place left to the dot is place 0).

Comment: @RanG. Asking how to convert 1750000000000000 shows that converting 1.75 does nothing whatsoever that helps with the problem. And of course 99% of the conversion to IEEE-754 single precision format is done at that point.

Comment: 1.75 × 10^15 = 110001101111001110110100000010110110110000000000000b = 1.1000110111100111011010000001011011011 × 2^50

Comment: Same question. Sucks that there is no answer here yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how the IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers works. It is not simply converting the number to binary.

Instead, the 32 bits that compose the representation of the floating-point number are split into 3 fields: sign, exponent, mantissa. Their sizes are 1bit, 8bit, and 23bit, respectively. 
Each *field* is written in binary basis (unsigned).

If the value of the exponent field is $e$, and the value of the mantissa field is $m$ then, the these 32bits represent the number
$$ 2^{e-127} \times (1 + m\cdot 2^{-23})$$
the $s$ bit determines if the number is positive or negative.

So, to represent the number $1.5\cdot 10^{15}$ you will need to set:
$s=0$ (positive), $e=177$, and $m=2787263$. Calculate
$2^{e-127} \times (1 + m\cdot 2^{-23}) = 2^{50} + 2787263\cdot 2^{27} = 1500000014041088$, which is the closest you can get to $1.5\cdot 10^{15}$ with 32bit representation.

Use https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html as a simple converter and a way to learn how this representation works.

(Oops, I demonstrated the above for 1.5e15, while the question was about 1.75e15. Nevermind, replace with $m=4649908$ to get 1.74999999e15).

Comment: Please let me know how you converted $10^{15}$ to $2^{50}$. Did you change the base using Logarithm ?

Comment: That's not how it works. Look again at the explanation. You need to find $e$ and $m$ that satisfy $2^{e-127}(1+m/2^{23})=1.75\cdot10^{15}$. The constraints are $0\le e \le 255$, and $0 \le m \le 2^{23}-1$.

Comment: I got the point that the number is split according to $2^{e-127}(1+m/2^{23})=1.75\cdot10^{15}$. I also understand that it must satisfy the condition as you mentioned above. But I want to know how you split exponent and mantissa. How you split mantissa=$4649908$ and exponent=$2^{50}$  Is there any formula. I know that to represent a number in floating point IEEE 32 bit format, we first convert the number in binary, then we normalize and bias the exponent and finally we write in the format $\pm(1.N)2^{E-127}$.

Comment: See a step by step conversion algorithm in https://blog.penjee.com/binary-numbers-floating-point-conversion/

Comment: The steps shown in (https://blog.penjee.com/binary-numbers-floating-point-conversion/) are the same way I learnt to convert.  The blog shows an example by converting $34.890625$ first to its binary form and then doing the other steps. My question was $1.75\times10^{15}$ which is equal to $1750000000000000$. How can I convert such a long number to its binary form, it is time consuming. Is there any way or shortcut to represent that long number. How do you extracted the exponent $2^{50}$.Just show me the calculation how you did for $m=4649908$ and $e=2^{50}$. your answer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this example: $1.75 \cdot 10^{15} = 175 \cdot 10^{13}$.

Quick and dirty: You convert 175 into a floating point number, lookup $10^{13}$ in a table, and multiply the two numbers.