# Convert $8.75×10^{6}$ to IEEE-32 format?

Tags: floating-point

There is a [similar](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109831/convert-1-75-times1015-to-ieee-32-format?newreg=97c71b87aae24e8bbd154348d4227fdb) question already asked on this site but does not have an answer as to how the 10<sup>x</sup> was converted into 2<sup>y</sup>. I know how to convert 8.75 or 875 into IEEE representation. But what about 10<sup>6</sup>? Surely there's a better way than expanding it and then converting it into binary.

Comment: Have you had a look at [IEEE-754 converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)?

Comment: Better way? No. Convert the number to an integer, then to a binary number.

Comment: @StefanB I have but I wanted to do it manually on paper.

Comment: @gnasher729 What if the number is huge like 8.75 x 10^30?